# Bidirectional messaged between two tizen wearble

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, samsung-gear-s2

I need to develop a chat application for Samsung watches running Tizen OS. How can I send messages between the watches?

I am assuming they are on the same Wifi, but we can't implement Wifi direct in Tizen wearables (it is only supported for mobile apps).

The last option would be to send SMS, but that would require them to be connected to mobile devices or have a separate SIM.

Thanks,

Comment: What kind of chat app it would be? There are some available like VOXER - voice chat. You can develop text chat which may need internet, if sim not supported.

Comment: @srkushwaha I need to send predefined text messages to 4-5 watch registered users. Would you recommend Nodejs+SocketIO for the private one to one chat?

Comment: Yes, it would be a perfect combination.

Comment: thanks @srkushwaha, but how do i maintain friend list? I dont want the chat room model for my application. I want to send predefined messages to registered users.

Answer (score 1):

another option is using Bluetooth.

There is a sample app in Tizen IDE:

Go to Tizen IDE > File > Project > Tizen Native Project > Online Sample > Network > Bluetooth Chat